# Is it possible to filter a powerbi chart from a URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi

I embedded a power bi report in an mvc application. I know that I can filter table with URL filter like the following:

```
?filter=Table/Field eq 'value'
```

But I need to filter a chart. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the term "table" means a table in the data source, not "table visual". So in essence, you are filtering the data. Any visual showing data from this table (datascouce table), either table (table visual), or chart, or any other visual, will display the filtered data. So the answer is yes.